# Note taking feature, line break and no content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm building the feature to take notes on my web app. I'm running into two problems:

I can't figure out how to recognize line breaks. I can hardcore text with line breaks, but when user clicks `Edit` it shows on the text the `<br>` and if he saves it just shows `<br>` in plain text.

Also if the user deletes all the text and clicks save it doesn't work and just prints `<textarea>`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
$('#edit').click(function() {
  $('#edit').hide();
  $('#note').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();
    $(this).html('<textarea style="width:inherit">' + content + '</textarea>');
  });
  $('#save').show();
});

$('#save').click(function() {
  $('#save').hide();
  $('textarea').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).val(); //.replace(/\n/g,"<br>");
    $(this).html(content);
    $(this).contents().unwrap();
  });
  $('#edit').show();
});
```

```css
#note {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 40rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h5 class="card-tittle">Note</h5>
  <hr>
  <div class="container index">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="jumbotron col-md-12" id="note">
        Test Text.
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>Edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="save"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not fill the textarea with the result of `.html()` - textarea can contain only text. And therefor the line breaks have to be simple `\n` as well, and not the HTML code for `br`. Try `.text()` instead and see if that does what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this...

```
$('#edit').click(function() {
  $('#edit').hide();
  $('#note').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html().replace(/<br>/g,"\n");
    $(this).html('<textarea style="width:inherit">' + content + '</textarea>');
  });
  $('#save').show();
});

$('#save').click(function() {
  $('#save').hide();
  $('textarea').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g,"<br>"); //.replace(/\n/g,"<br>");
    $(this).html("");
    $(this).append(content);
    $(this).contents().unwrap();
  });
  $('#edit').show();
});
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/hAL9pWWUFk

Comment: The Demo is not working. But I just tested and it is working. It still prints "<textarea>" when there is not content, but thats the only problem left and its awesome! Thanks man!